# how to store a function so it works only after clicked and results stays after refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
    function hd() {
        document.getElementById("Y").style.display = "none";
    }
```

```css
body {
display:grid;
place-content: center;
height:100vh;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="Y">i will be hidden</div>
<br>
<button onclick="hd();">click me</button>
```

---

The important thing is to store the function so it works even user refreshes the page I tried to use cookies but it did not work by just calling the function

Comment: In your code there is nothing setting a cookie or reading it; could you share the complete code, please?

Comment: the functions cannot be kept in memory to be reusable on a new page load

Comment: You'll have to use some sort of storage mechanism like cookies or the local storage. You'll also need to have a script that runs when the page loads to check if it should be hidden, and if so, hide it. But, the cookies and local storage are exceptionally easy to tamper with, so if that's something you're worried about I would suggest using a preprocessor instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set a flag with `localStorage` and then check whether this flag has been set already and call the function at startup again.

```js
function hd () {
    document.getElementById("Y").style.display = "none";
    localStorage.setItem("hidden", "yes");
}

if (localStorage.getItem("hidden")) {
    hd();
}
```